# VS Code JavaScript Intellisense is very slow on windows 10, but fast on Windows 11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense, code-completion

I have a react project using JavaScript files in which the Intellisense code completion suggestions are extremely slow when using Visual Studio Code in Windows 10. It takes 7 seconds to get a code completion suggestion.

However, when I open the same project on a Windows 11 machine, the code completion happens immediately with no delay.

The same VS Code extensions are installed on both machines, and both machines have 16GB of RAM.
These are the version information: (left side is on Windows 11 and it is fast, right side is on Windows 10 and is very slow)

[image]

Any suggestions on fixing this performance issue? I have tried disabling and re-enabling the "Typescript and JavaScript Language Features" extension but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: All other installed extensions (ideally there are none) are identical? Wonder if `Sandboxed: Yes` is significant.

Comment: @jarmod the installed extensions are identical. I am not sure about the Sandboxed, and I am not able to change that.

Comment: I have the same problem. Intellisense takes several seconds to show up and all code changes take a while to be processed. :(

Comment: @Markstar See my answer below. Check that you have "Sandboxed: Yes", as shown in the screenshot above.

Answer (score -1):

The problem resolved on it's own, after over a month. This was happening on my work PC. The support team must have pushed an update. The visual studio code version now has the **"Sandboxed" setting set to "Yes"**. This seems to have fixed the issue.

To enable Sandbox mode, go to the vs code settings and search for "Sandbox", and enable it. It is an experimental feature as of now.

[image]

Edit: as of October 2023, I see that sandbox is set to "No" again on my machine, (so the only thing that actually changed was the OS version, maybe there were compatibility issues with my previous windows OS version)

Comment: I don't have such a setting (v1.79.2, user setup). I wonder if the kind of installation makes difference.

Comment: @Markstar I am not sure about this. I have updated the answer with a screenshot showing my version (1.78.0 user setup) and the setting.

Comment: Here are [my settings](https://imgur.com/gallery/dJrYslL). Note that you are using an older version of VS Code. Maybe that option has been removed since?

Comment: @Markstar it looks like the sandbox settings was not what made it faster. It is set to "No" now and it's still working fast for me. I am not entirely sure. Perhaps it was the updated to the Windows OS version